# Pandas merge based on two columns removes a lot of the initial dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes representing the edge lists of a graph. One is a dataframe called `edge_list`, which contains all the edges in the graph and their corresponding weights (it's a weighted graph). The first few lines look like this:

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| source | target | value |
+--------+--------+-------+
|     31 |     25 |    17 |
|     45 |     21 |    67 |
|     68 |    127 |    10 |
|    ... |    ... |   ... |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

The second dataframe, called `edge_list_small`, has been created from `edge_list` by applying a filter, thus it only contains a subset of all edges. It also does not contain the `value` column (edge weights).

Now I want the weights of those edges in my small dataframe. Thus I figured I would merge the two based on the two columns, source and target. I am using:

```
complete_edge_list = small_edge_list.merge(edge_list,on=['source','target'])
```

There is a problem however.

```
print(len(edge_list), len(alpha_edge_list), len(complete_edge_list))
```

returns:

```
81,229,074 7,763,018 1,841,776
```

(commas added by me for readability). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I imagine you have duplicated edges, thus you end up with the combinations. Can you try: `complete_edge_list = small_edge_list.merge(edge_list.drop_duplicates(['source','target']), on=['source','target'])`? If this works you have to think how you want to deduplicate (are the weights also different?)

Comment: @mozway hi, I ran your command and this returns the same size dataframe, namely 1841776

Comment: are you sure this is unexpected to have this result? Could be fine

Comment: I am rechecking my files. Normally, I am expecting the result to have the size of the smaller dataframe + the weights column. Trying to see if there is some problem with the large dataframe.

Comment: What about `small_edge_list.merge(edge_list, on=['source','target'], how='left')`?

Comment: oh, damn, the last one retains the size of the small dataframe as expected. Mind turning this into an answer?

Comment: This means the small dataframe is not a subset of the large one, you have missing matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try a left merge:

```
complete_edge_list = small_edge_list.merge(edge_list, on=['source','target'],
                                           how='left')
```

and get the expected size, this means that the small dataframe is not a subset of the large one. You have missing matches and should have NaNs in the value column.